# Find and replace URLs and Email addresses

Tags: regex, vba, replace, ms-word

I'm able to use regex to find and replace IP addresses within a Microsoft Word Document, however I'm unable to do the same for Email addresses and URLs.

Here are the Regular Expressions for both URLs and Email addresses that have been tested so I know they work. I've been unable to get the macro to use them for find and replace.

URL: "((https|http)://)?([0-9a-zA-z.-]+).([0-9a-zA-Z.]{2,6})([0-9a-zA-z.-/]+)"

Email: "[a-zA-Z0-9.]+(\@)[a-zA-Z]+(.)[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,6}"

```
Sub Test()
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.MatchWildcards = True


    ' Remove IPs
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}"
        .Replacement.Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
        .Replacement.Text = "[IP REMOVED]"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

I tested my regular expressions using this code:

```
Sub Test_Regex()
    Dim objRegExp As Object
    Set objRegExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    objRegExp.Global = IsGlobal1
    objRegExp.Pattern = "((https|http)\:\/\/)?([0-9a-zA-z\.\-]+)\.([0-9a-zA-Z\.]{2,6})([0-9a-zA-z\.\-\/]+)?"
    objRegExp.IgnoreCase = Not IsCaseSensitive1
    RegExpReplace = objRegExp.Replace("google.com/asdasd/asda/asda.cssd", "RegexWorks")
    MsgBox (RegExpReplace)
End Sub
```

@Wiktor Stribiżew -- I tried using a regex based on your most recent comment in order to preserve the formatting but it's still stripping formatting when i run it.  Is this urlPattern regex the same as how you described it?

```
Sub Test()
    Dim urlPattern As String: urlPattern = "((https)\:\/\/)([0-9a-zA-z\.\-]+)\.([0-9a-zA-Z\.]{2,6})([0-9a-zA-z\.\-\/]+)"
    Dim regExp As Object
    Set regExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    With regExp
        .Pattern = urlPattern
        .Global = True
        ActiveDocument.Range = regExp.Replace(ActiveDocument.Range, "[REDACTED]")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What kind of regex engine does it use?

Comment: I don't think you need most of those escapes. Try this using a C-style string `"((https|http)://)?([0-9a-zA-z.-]+)\\.([0-9a-zA-Z.]{2,6})([0-9a-zA-Z./-]+)?"` I made a correction of `A-z` to `A-Z` in the class.

Comment: You are confused because `Selection.Find` uses *wildcard* expression, and inside the VBA code, you used a Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 *regular* expressions. The wildcard expressions do not have a *zero or more* / *zero or one* quantifiers. They cannot match empty strings.

Comment: if I understand what you're asking, it's VBA

Comment: @sln -- using the C-Style string, ..it's giving me the following error- and points at the Selection.find.execute line:

Run-time error '5560':

The Find What text contains a Pattern Match expression which is not valid.

Comment: @Wiktor - I'm fairly new to coding, but do understand what you're saying.. is there another way to make it work?

Comment: Use VBA code with the regex. There is a `RegExp.Replace` method. BTW, VBA strings are not C string literals, escape sequences cannot be defined in them, e.g. you cannot define a newline with `"\n"`.

Comment: I think you should set `MatchWildcards = FALSE`

Comment: Btw, what version Office are you using ?

Comment: @sln- using Office 13, and I tried the MatchWildcards=False with no luck

Comment: @Wiktor Thank you for steering me in the right direction I was able to get it to work using the following code.. however it's stripping the formatting for the entire document- any idea how to have the changes only impact the strings I'm searching?

Comment: Ok, to keep formatting, you need to use wildcards. And that means you need to use more than 2 patterns: you need to split them so as to cover all cases where you had optional subpatterns.

Answer (score 0):

I've tinkered a bit and converted your patterns to a Word compatible placeholder pattern since you need to do this with Word search/replace rather than regex engine.

**Important note:**

> In Word, placeholder patterns have a localized part, meaning that
>   quantifiers may be separated by semicolon rather than comma, depending
>   on your locale.

Also note, that the question mark does not mean "optional" in Word but rather "1 character of any sort". Therefore you will need a third pattern if you have URLs without http/s intro.

That said, this here should give you a good start. Note my use of semicolons in the {} quantifiers, please replace with comma if required by your locale. Also note my not using Selection:

```
Dim patterns As Variant
Dim placeholder As Variant

patterns = Array("[a-zA-Z0-9.]{1,}(\@)[a-zA-Z]{1,}.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,6}", "htt[ps]{1,2}://[0-9a-zA-Z.\-]{1,}[0-9a-zA-Z.\/\-_]{1,}", "[0-9a-zA-Z\-]{3,}.[0-9a-zA-Z.\/\-_]{3,}")
placeholder = Array("[EMAIL REMOVED]", "[URL REMOVED]", "[URL REMOVED]")

For i = 0 To 2
    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .text = patterns(i)
        .Replacement.text = placeholder(i)
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
Next i
```

Comment: Thank! This resolved my issue w/ formatting. The issue I have now is that the removals need to be in certain order.  I'll need to remove email addresses first, then URLs/Domains- if not done this way then email domains would be removed but not emails.  The RegEx worked, but while using commas instead of semicolons.

I've been trying to adjust the regex, but with no luck- the current regex only removes a domain (with http or https) if it ends w/ a "/".

Do you know how I'd be able to adjust this to accommodate Domains w/o URI paths as well as URLs that include full URI path?

Comment: That's all? No problem, simply swap the patterns! I have edited the code accordinglxy, including going back to commas in the quantifiers.

Comment: Thanks this is great!  I've been trying with no luck to make a MS Word friendly regex that will match on URLs/domains that don't start w/ http(s), and that will incorporate 'www.' as well as just a domain w/ no preceding text (google.com/asda/adasd).  Any idea on best approach here?

Comment: FYI: `htt[ps]{1,2}` matches `httpp` or `httss`, those are not valid protocols

Comment: @Toto: correct, but what are the odds of httpp://yadda or httss://yadda occuring without being a mistyped URL? I reckon zero.

Comment: Use `https?` that makes the `s` optional. Also `{1,}` can be rewritten `+`

Comment: @Toto: No, that does not work. This is using Word placeholder characters, not regular regex. Word behaves a little differently there.

Comment: OK. I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @LocEngineer that doesn't seem to work.. some of the example domain types I'm trying to encompass include: Google.google.com; Google.com; Google.com/asd-23.htm; www.google.com/33dsa/; google-google.com/123123/1232/2dfsd.pdf

Comment: I see. The pattern did have trouble with the first of your mentioned URLs. I have adjusted the code. Should work better now.